# C++ Visual Studio : Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to do a basic C++ score / grade system.  I want to validate the users input.  If the data is not a number, I want it to display an error message.  If it is, I want it to carry on.

However, if the user enters a letter, say for example 'a' or 'A'. It spits out this error :

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:
...ers\Alex\source\repos\worksheet_1.2a\Debug\worksheet_1.2a.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\appcrt\convert\isctype.cpp
Line: 36

Expression: c >= -1 && c <= 255
```

This is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>


using namespace std;  

int main()
{
    int score;

    // Recieve user input of score between 0-100. Stores input in score var
    cout << "\nWhat score did you get?\n" << endl;
    cin >> score;

    // Validating input

    if (!isdigit(score)) {
        if (score <= 59)
            cout << "Your grade is F" << endl;
        else if (score > 59 && score < 70)
            cout << "Your grade is D" << endl;
        else if (score > 69 && score < 80)
            cout << "Your grade is C" << endl;
        else if (score > 79 && score < 90)
            cout << "Your grade is B" << endl;
        else if (score > 89)
            cout << "Your grade is A" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Sorry, that is not a number. Please try again." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine if a number is entered, but not at all if a letter is.

I have looked at several other answers and videos based on 'Debug Assertion Failed' but cannot find one for this particular error.

Thanks for reading and help given!

Comment: When running in the debugger, what value does `score` have when a letter is entered? You probably need to have `char score;` instead of `int score;`.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather strange that `isdigit` takes an `int` not a `char`, because thats what it is for (from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit), emphazise mine):

> Checks if the given **character** is one of the 10 decimal digits:
>   0123456789.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the value of ch is not representable as
>   unsigned char and is not equal to EOF.

Seems like `isdigit` is quite some trap and you were lucky to get assertion fired. Anyhow, even though it takes an `int` you should pass a `char`:

```
 std::string s = "12asbc";
 std::cout << isdigit(s[0]);         // prints 1
 std::cout << isdigit(s[3]);         // prints 0
```

Anyhow your check isnt that meaningful. If it worked as you expected, you would only know that the number isnt a single digit, but your code would still fail if the user entered `abcd` or anything that is not a number. To check if the input was correct, you could do

```
int score;
if (std::cin >> score && 0 <= score && score <= 100) {
     // ok input
} else {
     // invalid input
}
```

Comment: I have tried this.  If the user inputs a character, it gives the error. But now, if the user gives a number, it does nothing.  The cursor jumps to the next line when 'Enter' is hit and just sits there and blinks?

Answer (score 0):

why did you type `!isdigit(score)` instead of `isdigit(score)`?
Don't put `!` in front of `isdigit(score)`.
`isdigit()` returns `True` when the argument is number.